# how to get list of pod names using kubernetes rest api (jsonpath)

Tags: kubernetes

is jsonPath supported in kubernetes http api ?

for ex; how the following translates to in http API ?

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items[0]}'
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not supported by the API, you would need to evaluate that jsonpath against the API response.

Comment: thank you .  The fieldSelector, labelSelector support also seem to be limited. I wonder if a IETF yang, restconf based API server would have saved the clients a lot of time and pain, also, would have enabled the clients to a great extent.  of course GraphQL is probably the latest answer for friendly APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use verbose flag `-v6` and above to see what API calls are actually being made

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items[0]}' -v6 2>&1
```

Output:

```
I0805 11:16:51.632841   76333 loader.go:375] Config loaded from file:  /Users/loganath/firetap/config-ctl1
I0805 11:16:53.666539   76333 round_trippers.go:444] GET https://10.x.x.x:6443/api/v1/namespaces/web/pods?limit=500 200 OK in 2021 milliseconds
I0805 11:16:54.901557   76333 table_printer.go:45] Unable to decode server response into a Table. Falling back to hardcoded types: attempt to decode non-Table object
```